# How do I pull information from this late-loading div?

Tags: selenium, screen-scraping, web-crawler, phantomjs

I have a Python-based Selenium web crawler with a PhantomJS driver and I'm trying to gather information from a page like this:

http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/3534-Stettinius-Ave-Cincinnati-OH-45208/34211495_zpid/

I want the element with this XPath: `//*[@id="transactionsTable"]`

I have a delay on the page, but it's not loading the information. Why not?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is scrolling-related, but I haven't QA'd it yet.  The driver has to scroll down to that point and then the page will load.

[This seems relevant](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-to-scroll-down-to-the-bottom-of-a-page).